# Can someone help me with the Canon MP250 printer driver?

Tags: printing, canon

Is there a way to install a driver for the Canon MP250 driver in Ubuntu 12.10.  I checked the Canon site and there is no driver but I am seeing if in Ubuntu that I can get a driver from typing something in terminal or if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with 12.04 and an MX310 printer - here's how it was fixed:

1. Download the tarball for the MX340 driver v3.30 from http://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0100272101.html
2. Extract, run install.sh, and instal the appropriate .deb file in /packages/ (may not appear to be installed)
3. Open the upper-right menu and click "Printers"
4. Click "Add". This will open up a list of printers the computers has found. Click "cancel".
5. Now, choose to add from a ppd file and browse to /usr/share/ppd/ and choose canonmx340.ppd
6. Click "OK" and set whatever settings you wish, and you're done! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO01kgl5xkk and here is the website to download the driver http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100236101.html

Answer (score 0):

Since **Ubuntu 20.04** you can add the **Canon MP250 printer + scanner drivers** by adding a ppa repository, install the drivers and add the printer to your printers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install the printer + scanner drivers:

```
sudo apt install cnijfilter-mp250series 
sudo apt install scangearmp-mp250series
```

After that you should be able to configure your printer via the "Printers" in your Desktop GUI.