# Trying to install Canon iP7250 printer

Tags: 13.10, printing, canon

I'm trying to install my Canon iP7250 printer on a fresh install of 13:10 64bit. Last time I installed it successfully via http://handytutorial.com/install-canon-printer-driver-for-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04 which entailed adding a repository via the terminal and then updating it. I then opened Synaptic and searched for my printer model and Synaptic then installed everything.

This time round I added the repositories but the update failed with the following error:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gru...amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gru...-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

An internet search failed to find another way of installing this printer so I'm stuck. My laptop also runs 64 bit 13:10 and the printer works, as I installed it months ago. Is there any way I can take something off that to use on this new machine?

Thank you all in advance

P.S. I have just found and downloaded the official Canon driver from the Canon website and extracted it, but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: Please see if this helps, http://askubuntu.com/questions/174474/installing-canon-lbp6000-in-ubuntu-12-04. To install the official drivers from Canon, you need to extract the tar files and run the scripts contained therein.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not very technical. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You can at least try installing the Canon official drivers and see if they work. They are fairly easy to install.

Comment: Also, you can take a look at this, http://askubuntu.com/questions/233416/can-someone-help-me-with-the-canon-mp250-printer-driver

Comment: Thanks for the further information. I tried double clicking on install.sh and all it did was open a text file, so I'm none the wiser! In the Windoze world I could simply double click the .exe and it would install, but Ubuntu appears to be a bit more complicated to beginners like me.

Comment: Press `Ctrl-Alt-t`, you get a terminal. Use `cd` to move to the directory where `install.sh` is, type `. ./install.sh` and press `Enter`. That will execute this file. I will also face the same kind of problem if you ask me to sit at some Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks MMA for your help - much appreciated. Sorry to be thick, but the Canon driver is in a folder on the desktop which I have already extracted. I tried typing cd desktop in the terminal and it says "no such file or directory". What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: The command will be `cd Desktop/`, please note the uppercase D. Cases are important in Linux.

Comment: Thanks MMA. I successfully got to the desktop but I presume that, because the install.sh file is inside a folder called cnijfilter-ip7200series-3.80-1-deb, I need to get inside that folder. I tried using ./install.sh and adding the name of the file and that didn't work. Then I tried cd nameoffile/ and that didn't work either, so I'm still stuck. Sorry to be such a pain! I notice that the last entry on the Handy Tutorial website was in August, so I wonder if the owner of the site will be updating it.

Comment: A search on Duck Duck Go brought me to https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+question/226171 where I managed to add another repository and managed to install the printer driver that way. Thank you to all of you for your help.

Comment: Looks like an excellent resource. Will resort to this one should at some point I fail to coax my present driver installation to work. Till that time, do not want to perturb my working system. Though at this moment, I need to execute a home made script before a print.

Answer (score 1):

A search on Duck Duck Go brought me to http://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+question/226171 where I managed to add another repository and managed to install the printer driver that way.

The repository is https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk

Add the repository using these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
```